# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que cada vez que se refresque la pagina, un enlace de un botón cambie?

Tags: php, html, web

¿Cómo puedo hacer que cada vez que se refresque la pagina, un enlace de un botón cambie? La verdad, lo necesito urgentemente para mi foro. Me dan igual los requisitos que hagan falta y lo que necesite para hacerlo.

Código:

```
<a class="wb_button" href="https://cutsouf.com/st?api=1fa3b56b7330118641ae6accd1b6700739076377&amp;url=https://cutearn.ca/st?api=d4f511a4c78629e30ea44b95fe1c4165a9a3684d&amp;url=https://paste.rmlh.uk/judesacuvu.java" target="_blank"><span>Generate Account</span></a>
```

(quiero que cambie esta url: "https://cutsouf.com/st?api=1fa3b56b7330118641ae6accd1b6700739076377&)

Comment: Tienes el código del HTML y de tu JS para poder orientarme mejor con tu pregunta?

Comment: Modifiqué la descripción. Ahí está. Me equivoque al poner javascript, pues ahi no lo utilizo.

Comment: la opción más rápida es que mandes parámetros get y al cargar tú página puedas decidir que acciones ejecutar en base a los parámetro.

Comment: Utiliza una variable de sesión con un contador o un booleano por cada carga

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/118078)

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solucion es que pongas en un array los diferentes enlaces que quieres para el boton. Tambíen poner un contador que suma 1 cada vez que recarga la página. Para finalizar es poner el contador en módulo numero de enlaces que hay en el array.

Por ejemplo se ha reargado la página 20 veces y tienes 4 enlaces, pues iria a la posicion 0 del array de la URl.

Espero que haya sido de ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: deberías colocar en código también tu explicación

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando Jquery, podrias hacer lo siguiente:

Despues de hacer la consulta que haga que se refresque la pagina ejemplo:

```
$.ajax
    ({
      // En caso de que hicieras el envio al servidor usando Ajax

      success: function(data)
      {

         $("$enlaceQueNecesitas").attr('href','Url que necesitas ahora que tenga');
      } 
    })
```

Ojo estoy suponiendo que tienes un enlace en el sitio:

```
<a id="enlaceQueNecesitas" href='/enlace/' class='clase que haga que tenga forma de boton'>Ir al sitio</a>
```

Espero haberte dado así sea alguna luz.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que no haya entendido tu pregunta. No has dicho con que lo quieres cambiar. En el siguiente ejemplo cambio tu enlace por el de codepen.

```js
let wbbutton = document.querySelector(".wb_button")
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
  wbbutton.setAttribute("href","https://codepen.io")
})
```

```html
<a class="wb_button" href="https://cutsouf.com/st?api=1fa3b56b7330118641ae6accd1b6700739076377&amp;url=https://cutearn.ca/st?api=d4f511a4c78629e30ea44b95fe1c4165a9a3684d&amp;url=https://paste.rmlh.uk/judesacuvu.java" target="_blank"><span>Generate Account</span></a>
```

Comment: Si no se está seguro es mejor no responder.